# Why can't enter pdb debugger, by M-X pdb test.py?

Tags: python, emacs

Under Emacs, I opened a .py file. I want to debug it using pdb.

I hit `M-x pdb`, then the bottom bar of Emacs asks me:

> Run /usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py (like this): /usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py test.py

I hit `Enter`. Then it creates a new buffer showing

> Current directory is ~/python_programs/

It doesn't show the prompt of pdb. When I enter pdb commands such as `n`, they are just entered that new buffer, as if I were editing the buffer. It seems that no pdb is running.

But if I invoke pdb again for my .py file in the same way as above, the bottom bar of Emacs will say:

> This program is already being debugged

I am baffled. Do I miss something?

Thanks.

p.s. If it matters, I am using python-mode.el, but I guess the problem has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs command `pdb` is defined in core. It offers the last file in its history for debugging.
Seems you have to replace test.py by the current buffer-file-name.

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by "It offers the last file in its history for debugging", and "the current buffer-file-name"? The buffer name that opens test.py is still `test.py` by the way.

Comment: @Tim If the correct file is selected, please file a bug-report.